# DocusignAPI - Sign here tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking to integrate DocuSignAPI (using the .net library from Github) in our application. As the documents will be different, I'm looking into how I can add sign here tabs to different documents. I've looked at navigating to SenderViewUrl, but it needs authentication. 
Is there any recommended way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar goal.  What worked for me was to start small by following the Quick Start step by step instructions here:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call
and then here:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures

Their example API call does create a simple signature tab. The code fragment looks like this:

```
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "100",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
```

I recommend you get their example code to work, and then build up other logic and features that you need for your application.

-Peter

Comment: awesome answer, it's a great way to get your feet wet with the DocuSign API!

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've so far looked into this and have found the sample very useful. The one item that I'm stumped upon is to add the sign here boxes programatically, but without hardcoding the x and y positions. Even better is that I upload the document to Docusign's portal, and then allow the user to place the sign here boxes on the document. This will give users better control regarding the placement.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use an anchor. 
When you define the tab, you can specify a text contained in the document where you want to add the tab.
It is very useful when the document to sign is always different and so you do not know the x and y but it contains the same words where the user has to sign.

It can help also to use an invisible text for the anchors (white font color on white background). In this way it is easier to specify the anchors and add the signature in the exact position.

Please refer to:

[Anchoring Tabs](https://www.docusign.co.uk/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm)

[Code Walkthrough _ Anchor Tabs](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Anchor-Tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some of the code that you have so far? 
The library supports adding tabs programmatically and you can have different tabs for different documents (as well as different recipients). As for authentication - API calls require it but the url to sign and send can work for about 20 minutes without authentication (once you make the API call to get it). 
Let's see if you can explain a bit more what you're doing and what issues you run into and I'll try to further help you.

Inbar

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm currently working off the sample code provided. Just looking for best way to approach this. In general, trying to add the sign here boxes programatically, but without hard coding the x/y positions.