# Is there any way to move the 'signature tag' over the page to sign using Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have been trying merge DocuSign in my application to make the user sign the documents I upload. Currently DocuSign allows us to add the signature tag at a static location, where we can provide the co-ordinates programmatically.

I would like to have a functionality where the signer can move the Signature tag anywhere over the page and insert the signature at the selected location.

Is there any good way to do this using DocuSign API's. Are there any DocuSign API's currently which do this?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the signer to have the ability to dynamically position where the signature will go? Just send the document with no tabs at all and the signer will be asked to select the type of signing field (signature, initials, date, etc) and then choose its placement.

However, this is typically not a good UI. Instead, it is better for the *sender* to pick where the signer should sign. This can also be done dynamically using the "Sender View."

Comment: Thanks Larry, regarding the first option you mentioned, is there any way to disable the menu options other than 'Signature'?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about the part where the signer can move the tabs. But Anchor-Tabs sound like something that might help. I have asked a question on it a few minutes ago with sample code.

[DocusignApi - Attachment with SignHere tab on the third page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684981/docusignapi-attachment-with-signhere-tab-on-the-third-page)

The following link might also help.

[DocusignAPI - Sign here tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657525/docusignapi-sign-here-tabs)